# Mime type "application/CDFV2-corrupt" for Outlook msg file using PHP's finfo_file

Tags: php, outlook, mime-types, fileinfo, msg

I did a little research on Outlook `msg` files and I expected the mime type to be `application/vnd.ms-outlook`.  But when I use `finfo_file()`, I get `application/CDFV2-corrupt`.  I've since tried it on two different servers (my local Centos box and my Centos VPS) and get the same results.  Has anyone tried this code and do you get the same results as me?  How can I use PHP to get the mime type of a `msg` file?

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$filetype=finfo_file($finfo, 'test.msg');
echo($filetype);
?>
```

Output:

```
application/CDFV2-corrupt
```

Comment: I saw someone posted an answer, but clicked it and it had been deleted.  Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I also found some old XLS files that give this same MIME type.
Apparently it stands for "Composite Document File V2", old XLS files use that file format.

Either the file actually is slightly corrupt or non-conformant (perhaps in the metadata), or libmagic has a bug with reading some variant of the format.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Try `application/octet-stream`. As long as the file extension is correct (.MSG) Outlook will be able to open the MSG file just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Part of my reason to check mime was to verify that the file is what it seems.

Comment: MIME type would be checked by an email client or the browser, but the actual app that opens it on the Windows side would only access the file name (and hence the extension).

Comment: `application/binary` is not a valid MIME type, should be `application/octet-stream`.